# 'int' object not callable heap sort function

Tags: python, heapsort

'int' Object Not Callable Heap Sort Function

Im trying to create a function that return a sorted list but im getting the following error: "new_value = sort_heap.deleteMin() 'int' object is not callable"

This is the code:

```
class MinHeap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.heap=[]


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.heap}'

    __repr__=__str__


    def parent(self,index):
        # -- YOUR CODE STARTS HERE

        if index>len(self) or index<=1:
            return None

        else:
            return self.heap[index//2-1]

    def leftChild(self,index):
        # -- YOUR CODE STARTS HERE

        if index<1 or 2*index>len(self):
            return None

        else:
            return self.heap[2*index-1]



    def rightChild(self,index):


        if index<1 or 2*index>len(self):
            return None

        else:
            return self.heap[2*index-1]




    def __len__(self):

        return len(self.heap)



    def insert(self,x):

        self.heap.append(x)
        current = len(self)

        while self.parent(current) is not None and self.parent(current)>x:

            self.heap[current-1], self.heap[current//2-1] = self.heap[current//2-1], self.heap[current-1]
            current = current//2



    @property 
    def deleteMin(self):
        if len(self)==0:
            return None        
        elif len(self)==1:
            out=self.heap[0]
            self.heap=[]
            return out



        deleted = self.heap[0]
        current = 1
        self.heap[0] = self.heap[len(self)-1]
        x = self.heap.pop()
        moved_value = self.heap[0]
        while self.leftChild(current) is not None:
            left=self.leftChild(current)
            right=self.rightChild(current)
            if right is not None:
                if left<=right and left<moved_value:
                    self.heap[current-1], self.heap[current*2] = self.heap[current*2], self.heap[current-1]
                    current = current *2 
                elif left>right and right<moved_value:
                    self.heap[current-1], self.heap[current*2] = self.heap[current*2], self.heap[current-1]
                    current = (current*2) + 1
                else:
                    break
            else:
                if left<moved_value:
                    self.heap[current-1], self.heap[(current*2)-1] = self.heap[(current*2)-1], self.heap[current-1]
                    current = current*2
                else:
                    break
        return deleted
def heapSort(numList):
    '''
       >>> heapSort([9,7,4,1,2,4,8,7,0,-1])
       [-1, 0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 7, 7, 8, 9]
    '''
    sort_heap = MinHeap()
    for i in range (len(numList)):
        sort_heap.insert(numList[i])
    sortedList= []
    lenght=len(numList)
    while lenght >0:
        new_value = sort_heap.deleteMin()
        sortedList.append(new_value)
        lenght -= 1

    return sortedList
```

The MinHeap class is a given but I'm allow to modify it. Could Someone please help? Thanks

Comment: Please repair the formatting of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your (btw wrong formatted code, please redo the formatting) code I can see, that `deleteMin` is a `@property` and not a class method. Therefore you shuld write:

```
new_value = sort_heap.deleteMin
#                              ^ You see, no brackets here
```

Comment: Or better yet, delete the `@property` decorator and leave the call to this method as it is.  It would be *extremely* unexpected for access to a property to cause removal of data.

Comment: Absolutely, but if you look at the code, it looks like, the top bit was given in some sort and there should not be done any changes, or at least I assumed that